# Sentence tokenization for sentence without punctuation

Tags: python, nlp, python-3.x, nltk, spacy

I wish to perform sentence tokenization for sentence without punctuation, below is the code:

```
import nltk

def segment_sentences(text):
    # Download the Punkt tokenizer if necessary
    nltk.download('punkt')
    
    # Tokenize the text into sentences
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
    
    return sentences

input_text = "hello how are you today i hope you're doing well have a great day"

sentences = segment_sentences(input_text)

# Print the segmented sentences
for sentence in sentences:
    print(sentence)
```

Desired output

```
hello how are you today
i hope you're doing well
have a great day
```

But current output

```
hello how are you today i hope you're doing well have a great day
```

How should I address it?

Comment: Can you explain how is an inference engine intended/expected to know how to segment the words into sentences?

Answer (score 4):

You can apply a previous step to add punctuation and proper casing to the text, and then segment the sentences. For this, you may use [Re-punctuate](https://huggingface.co/SJ-Ray/Re-Punctuate). When applied to your text, Re-punctuate gives the following output:

```
Hello, how are you today? I hope you're doing well. Have a great day.
```

Then, if we apply your NLTK code to it, we obtain this output:

```
Hello, how are you today?
I hope you're doing well.
Have a great day.
```